# convert scientific notation to datetime

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

How can I convert date from seconds to date format.

I have a table containing information about lat, long and time.
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUw5A.png)

```
f_table['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(f_table['dt'])
f_table["dt"]
```

it results like this:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdNQO.png)

but the output is wrong actually the date is 20160628 but it converted to 1970.

My desired output:
`24-April-2014`

Comment: What is the input?

Comment: A netcdf file of satellite data

Comment: Can you provide us a sample input

Comment: sorry unable to format the question properly ... the inputs are  28.359062 69.693673 5.204486e+08 .

Comment: 5.204486e+08  is number of seconds?

Comment: Yes , it is in seconds

Comment: Cool, check my answer below!

Answer (score 2):

The unit needs to be nanoseconds, so you need to multiply with 1e9

```
f_table['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(f_table['dt'] * 1e9)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
#Split your string to extract timestamp, I am assuming a single space between each float
op = "28.359062 69.693673 5.204486e+08"
ts = float(op.split()[2])

from datetime import datetime
#Timestamp to datetime object
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)
#Datetime object to string
dt_str = dt.strftime('%m-%B-%Y')
print(dt_str)
#06-June-1986
```

Comment: dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(f_table["dt"]) TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Comment: You need to extract out the timestamp from your string

Comment: Okay I updated the answer to do just that! have a look!

Comment: I updated my question, actually I am working on panda series